# Drawing the correct card from a deck

Tags: games, jaccard-similarity

Saw this on an old western show.

A poker player believes the dealer is switching decks of cards.

The player has 5 cards in his hand and at the end of a hand, he smudges all of them with cigar ashes.  One of them is the ace of hearts.  All cards are returned to the original deck.

The dealer’s accomplice creates a diversion and the dealer sneakily switches decks.

With only 2 players (dealer and the player), a game of 5 card stud ensues, all cards face up.
When the last card is played which is ace of hearts, it comes up without the smudge.  Therefore the player concludes the dealer is cheating.

So, what are the odds out of 10 cards played from the new deck that ONE of the 5 cards smudged will show up.  (this assumes the new deck has the same makeup as the old deck)….

Thanks, John

Comment: For a set of 52, the probability is 0.430 to have exactly one smudged card within the 10 played, that is, the odds is 1:1.32. (This is calculated like lotto probabilities.) Welcome to Cross Validated!